# Can my child with a UK ILR travel to India and return to UK with less than six months Indian passport validity when returning to UK?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, passport-renewals, uk-residents

My child is an Indian citizen by descent and has UK Indefinite Leave to Remain. His passport is valid for more than six months when we travel to India, but at the time of returning back to the UK, it will be less than six months (by 15 days).

We are travelling by Qatar Airlines with a two and a half hour layover in Doha. We are not going out of the airport there, just to be clear.

Will we face any issues?

I tried to get his passport reissued/renewed from the UK but I am not getting VFS slots, and now the travel date is too close.

Comment: We are travelling via Qatar airlines, with a 2.5 hrs change at Doha. We are not going out of airport just to be clear.

Comment: Please add this information into your question by using the "edit" button below the question text. Questions persist, but comments sometimes do not.

Comment: Timatic says *’Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to residents of the United Kingdom must be valid on arrival.’* It also lists a number of other criteria relating to the residence permit held https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&country=/GB You can enter all the details of the trip on the IATA site (including passport expiry date and transit information) to get a reliable answer https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ Without knowing all that I’m not sure anyone can answer

Comment: Did you check possibility of renewing from India? It is way faster and you will get it in a few days.

Answer (score 4):

The UK has no minimum passport validity for long term visa holders beyond the passport must be valid on arrival. It appears there is neither any minimum validity for those transiting Qatar. From the Qatar airways [travel requirements](https://www.qatarairways.com/en-gb/travel-alerts/requirements.html) page, no minimum validity for Qatar is mentioned with your itinerary.